# Styling css transform with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I cannot seem to add a transform to the body element (having a mega brain block as to why its not working). I am trying to experiment with some scrolling effects.

Progress thus far:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
var previousScrollPos = 0;
var currentScrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;
var transformValue = -500px;
if(currentScrollPos > previousScrollPos) {
        document.body.style.transform = "translate-y(transformValue)";
    }
}
```

UPDATE
 This is now my working code

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', scroller)

function scroller() {
    var previousScrollPos = 0;
    var currentScrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;
    var nextScrollPos = 0;
    if (currentScrollPos > previousScrollPos) {
        nextScrollPos = nextScrollPos - 100;
        document.body.style.transform = "translateY(" + nextScrollPos + "vh)";
    } else {
        nextScrollPos = nextScrollPos + 100;
        document.body.style.transform = "translateY(" + previousScrollPos + "vh)";
    }

}
```

Comment: `-500px` results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. `px` is not a built-in single or set of characters that can be appended to JavaScript primitive number or decimals without resulting in a syntax error. Is `transition` property set at CSS?

Comment: you are aware that `"translate-y(transformValue)"` does not work this way?

Comment: @GottZ can you not use a stored variable value then to style it?

Comment: `-500px` is a string. You can't store it like an integer as you're doing here. Put quotes around it. And when calling the variable, concetenate it like `"sting "+ transformValue +" string"`.

Comment: @rufus _"-500px is not a syntax error"_?

Comment: Adding to what guest271314 has said: I think if you are using something like -500px, you need to put it in a string, such as "-500px".

Comment: @guest271314 sorry i thought you were referring to it as if i added it in error when i didnt.

Comment: @icecub of course thats it! thanks for making me realise my daft error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Syntax is wrong. translating the Y axis is written in camelcase like this:

transform: translateY(-500px);

So the right way to write it should be:

```
...
var transformValue = -500;
if(currentScrollPos > previousScrollPos) {
        document.body.style.transform = "translateY(" + transformValue + "px)";
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, I kind of like this better than what's been suggested in the comments of putting "-500px" in quotes. This way, you can perform mathematical operations on it too. +1

Comment: this is exactly what i was trying to achieve, thank you very much for this much appreciated. Also thanks to everyone else for their suggestions and for pointing out my mistakes. Been a long day!

Comment: I have just updated my post with my working code from your answer which works great. The problem i am now having is the down scroll only seems to work once. Would anyone know why the scroll wont fire on every scroll down?

Comment: @rufus that would be another question. But looking into your code, you are resetting the previous & nextScrollPos values on each scroll. If I got what you're trying to do right, they should be outside the scroll callback so you can compare with the real previous value.